# In what instances would a multi 4-node cluster make more sense over two 2-node clusters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing

What are the benefits / drawbacks in these instances?  Particularly interested in SQL Server 2008: active/active/active/active vs active/active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benefits of two 2-node clusters:

- Cheaper licensing if you're going to use Standard
- More storage flexibility if you may use two different SANs down the road
- Easier version upgrades if one cluster needs to move forward and the other needs to stay behind for legacy apps
- Isolated security if you have 3rd party vendor apps on there and they need to RDP in, lessens the chance that they'll screw up other services

Benefits of one 4-node cluster:

- Easier redistribution of load (including failovers) if you're doing instance stacking

Answer (score 0):

With a four node cluster the nice thing is that you have more failover options as you have three nodes available when you down a machine.  With some proper cluster and instance config you can make this pretty robust.

The downside is the license cost.  SQL Server 2005 and higher only supports 2 node clusters with standard edition, so building a 4 node cluster requires Enterprise Edition or higher for the SQL Server edition.  This will greatly increase the license costs of SQL Server if you were planning on using SQL Server Standard Edition.